# How to use boolean to toggle display of environment that may contain verbatim?

Tags: environments, verbatim, ifthenelse

I'd like to create an environment `solution` that either displays its contents or nothing depending on whether the boolean `solutions` is set. Currently I'm trying:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthenx}
\newboolean{solutions}
\setboolean{solutions}{true}

\usepackage{color}
\newenvironment{solution}%
{%
\ifsolutions%
\color{red}
\subsubsection*{Solution}%
}%
{%
\fi%
}

\begin{document}

Write some code:
\begin{solution}
\begin{verbatim}
a = 1;
a++;
\end{verbatim}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

This works great for `\setboolean{solutions}{true}` but fails for `\setboolean{solutions}{false}`. I get an error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 21.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> foo

?
```

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204450/13600 recommends using the environ package, but this is not a real environment so it fails if with an verbatim environment in the `\BODY`. In turn, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51256/13600 recommends some work arounds for environ like using special macros or external files.

Is there a cleaner way to do what I want?

Comment: You want to have a look at the `comment` package.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159820/4427, particularly the answer by the author of `comment`.

Comment: I'm a little lost, it seems `comment` has the same problems with verbatim.

Comment: The author said he has fixed the issue.

Comment: I have version 3.8 and still having issues (but maybe I'm not doing exactly what you intend.)

Answer (score 2):

When TeX sees `\iffalse` (maybe during macro expansion), it starts skipping tokens until finding the matching `\fi`, ***without*** any macro expansion. It just takes a count of the (explicit) conditionals it finds, in order to determine the proper nesting.

Thus the `\fi` hidden in `\end{solutions}` is never scanned when the boolean is set to false.

This seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{color}
\newenvironment{solution}
  {\color{red}\subsubsection*{Solution}}
  {}

%\excludecomment{solution}

\begin{document}

Write some code:
\begin{solution}
á prògrâm
\begin{verbatim}
a = 1;
a++;
\end{verbatim}
\end{solution}

some text following

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to print the solutions, just uncomment the line

```
%\excludecomment{solution}
```

to

```
\excludecomment{solution}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. Is there a way to tie the exclusion to my boolean `solutions` ?

Comment: @AlecJacobson No. When skipping text in the false branch of a conditional, TeX doesn't expand macros, so it cannot get to see the `\fi` that only appears when `\end{solutions}` is expanded.

Comment: OK, I think I can work around that. This is working for verbatim but not if my solution contents contains a `includegraphics`. What's up with that?